# Secure text not apear proper in textfield swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am using Montserrat font for password textfield and enable secure text entry option from xcode but password font is not apearing correct. i have tried but didn't find any solution.

Output

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: It should work. BTW you can convert each character into desired character in `shouldCharacterChange` event of `textField`.

Comment: @TheTiger you mean replace each character with ( * ) ?

Comment: Exactly...! Just disable the secure text entry and do it manually.

Comment: Sorry but since a secure text field displays only bullets, what is the point of changing its font???

Comment: Yes right @matt but when i entered in password textfield then i am getting above result insted of bullets

Comment: @Nikunj5294 Means do not change the password field font as it only shows bullets. Just use the default font.

Comment: @Nikunj5294 So it didn't work? Not possible

Comment: yes @TheTiger but I have used Montserrat font as a system font by custom font class so its taking default font Montserrat, and now I find the solution,  set font by programmatically and its working fine. 

textfield.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 15)

Comment: @TheTiger there are show password option if user will click on show password then  will get Helvetica-Neue but in whole app I am using Montserrat that's why I have added that font, BTW now its working fine thanks

Comment: @Nikunj5294 In that case you can toggle the font while `secureTextEntry = true` use `Helvetica` font otherwise use `Montserrat`.

Comment: Yes you are right @TheTiger also this option will work

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a font that doesn't contain the bullet character or has a different character at that code point. You either need to use a font that has the bullet character at the expected code point or not change the font at all (changing the font size to match your UI can be achieved by querying the font from the text field, then [increasing its size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619032-withsize) and assigning that back to the text field).